# Read lists into columns of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas

I want to load lists into columns of a pandas DataFrame but cannot seem to do this simply.  This is an example of what I want using `transpose()` but I would think that is unnecessary:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,10)
In [4]: y = np.sin(x)
In [5]: data = pd.DataFrame(data=[x,y]).transpose()
In [6]: data.columns = ['x', 'sin(x)']
In [7]: data
Out[7]: 
          x        sin(x)
0  0.000000  0.000000e+00
1  0.349066  3.420201e-01
2  0.698132  6.427876e-01
3  1.047198  8.660254e-01
4  1.396263  9.848078e-01
5  1.745329  9.848078e-01
6  2.094395  8.660254e-01
7  2.443461  6.427876e-01
8  2.792527  3.420201e-01
9  3.141593  1.224647e-16

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

Is there a way to directly load each list into a column to eliminate the transpose and insert the column labels when creating the DataFrame?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Someone just recommended creating a dictionary from the data then loading that into the DataFrame like this:

```
In [8]: data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'sin(x)': y})
In [9]: data
Out[9]: 
          x        sin(x)
0  0.000000  0.000000e+00
1  0.349066  3.420201e-01
2  0.698132  6.427876e-01
3  1.047198  8.660254e-01
4  1.396263  9.848078e-01
5  1.745329  9.848078e-01
6  2.094395  8.660254e-01
7  2.443461  6.427876e-01
8  2.792527  3.420201e-01
9  3.141593  1.224647e-16

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

Note than a dictionary is an unordered set of key-value pairs.  If you care about the column orders, you should pass a list of the ordered key values to be used (you can also use this list to only include some of the dict entries):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'sin(x)': y}, columns=['x', 'sin(x)'])
```

Comment: You can specify column order this way:

In [9]: In [5]: data = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'sin(x)':y}, columns=['x','sin(x)'])

Comment: You're missing quotes in the dictionary initialization.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell As of pandas version 0.25.0: If data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html))

Answer (score 7):

Here's another 1-line solution preserving the specified order, without typing `x` and `sin(x)` twice:

```
data = pd.concat([pd.Series(x,name='x'),pd.Series(y,name='sin(x)')], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the column names, you can use this:

`pd.DataFrame(zip(*[x,y]))`

run-time-wise it is as fast as the dict option, and both are much faster than using transpose.