# Take multiple lists into dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

How do I take multiple lists and put them as different columns in a python dataframe? I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014618/read-lists-into-columns-of-pandas-dataframe) but had some trouble.

Attempt 1:

- Have three lists, and zip them together and use that `res = zip(lst1,lst2,lst3)`
- Yields just one column

Attempt 2:

```
percentile_list = pd.DataFrame({'lst1Tite' : [lst1],
                                'lst2Tite' : [lst2],
                                'lst3Tite' : [lst3] }, 
                                columns=['lst1Tite','lst1Tite', 'lst1Tite'])
```

- yields either one row by 3 columns (the way above) or if I transpose it is 3 rows and 1 column

How do I get a 100 row (length of each independent list) by 3 column (three lists) pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 499, accepted):

I think you're almost there, try removing the extra square brackets around the `lst`'s (Also you don't need to specify the column names when you're creating a dataframe from a dict like this):

```
import pandas as pd
lst1 = range(100)
lst2 = range(100)
lst3 = range(100)
percentile_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {'lst1Title': lst1,
     'lst2Title': lst2,
     'lst3Title': lst3
    })

percentile_list
    lst1Title  lst2Title  lst3Title
0          0         0         0
1          1         1         1
2          2         2         2
3          3         3         3
4          4         4         4
5          5         5         5
6          6         6         6
...
```

If you need a more performant solution you can use `np.column_stack` rather than `zip` as in your first attempt, this has around a 2x speedup on the example here, however comes at bit of a cost of readability in my opinion:

```
import numpy as np
percentile_list = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([lst1, lst2, lst3]), 
                               columns=['lst1Title', 'lst2Title', 'lst3Title'])
```

Comment: Is np.column_stack a view, or does it copy the data. (If copy, it seems like this could be much more efficient (O(1), not O(n)).

Comment: @maxymoo can column names be automatically set to the list name?

Comment: numpy column stack does not work well if the lists are of different datatypes

Answer (score 92):

Adding to [Aditya Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2784184/)'s answer here. There is no need of using map. You can do it simply by:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2, lst3)))
```

This will set the column's names as 0,1,2. To set your own column names, you can pass the keyword argument `columns` to the method above.

```
pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst1, lst2, lst3)),
              columns=['lst1_title','lst2_title', 'lst3_title'])
```

Comment: In Python 3.8, and Pandas 1.0, we don't need to use list function, since DataFrame expects an iterable, and zip() returns an iterable object. So, `pd.DataFrame(zip(lst1, lst2, lst3))` should also do.

Answer (score 20):

Adding one more scalable solution.

```
lists = [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4]
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in lists], axis=1)
```

Comment: can you explain this one a bit?

Comment: You join (concat) series vertically (axis=1) to create DataFrame from the list of lists

Answer (score 18):

There are several ways to create a dataframe from multiple lists.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[5,6,7,8]
list3=[9,10,11,12]
```

1. `pd.DataFrame({'list1':list1, 'list2':list2, 'list3'=list3})`
2. `pd.DataFrame(data=zip(list1,list2,list3),columns=['list1','list2','list3'])`

Answer (score 14):

Just adding that using the first approach it can be done as -

```
pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, zip(lst1,lst2,lst3))))
```

Answer (score 11):

Adding to above answers, we can create on the fly

```
df= pd.DataFrame()
list1 = list(range(10))
list2 = list(range(10,20))
df['list1'] = list1
df['list2'] = list2
print(df)
```

hope it helps !

Answer (score 5):

@oopsi used `pd.concat()` but didn't include the column names.  You could do the following, which, unlike the first solution in the accepted answer, gives you control over the column order (avoids dicts, which are unordered):

```
import pandas as pd
lst1 = range(100)
lst2 = range(100)
lst3 = range(100)

s1=pd.Series(lst1,name='lst1Title')
s2=pd.Series(lst2,name='lst2Title')
s3=pd.Series(lst3 ,name='lst3Title')
percentile_list = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3], axis=1)

percentile_list
Out[2]: 
    lst1Title  lst2Title  lst3Title
0           0          0          0
1           1          1          1
2           2          2          2
3           3          3          3
4           4          4          4
5           5          5          5
6           6          6          6
7           7          7          7
8           8          8          8
...
```

Comment: `dict`s are not unordered for python > 2

Answer (score 4):

you can simply use this following code

```
train_data['labels']= train_data[["LABEL1","LABEL1","LABEL2","LABEL3","LABEL4","LABEL5","LABEL6","LABEL7"]].values.tolist()
train_df = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=['text','labels'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did it like this (python 3.9):

```py
import pandas as pd
my_dict=dict(x=x, y=y, z=z) # Set column ordering here
my_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
```

This seems to be reasonably straightforward (albeit in 2022) unless I am missing something obvious...

In python 2 one could've used a `collections.OrderedDict()`.