# separating column for only one time by separator in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like

```
abc:def How I met her
ter:kpefe Hi I am this
```

I want the column to be like this

```
a       b         c
abc    def     How I met her
ter    kpefe   Hi I am this
```

I want to separate it into 3 column So I am using

```
data = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=" |:", header = None, names=["a", "b", "c"])
```

which is giving many column beside a, b and c

Comment: Could you make your data clearer and maybe show the result that you want as well. thx

Comment: done @Niche.P thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My stab at this uses the `csv` library to read the input into lists since it needs to be (heavily) sanitized before it can be neatly put into a DataFrame like you want.

```
# Python 3.5
import pandas as pd 
import csv 

col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []

with open('path/to/the/file.txt', newline='') as txt:
    reader = csv.reader(txt)
    for row in reader:
        # Get rid of brackets and ' on both ends of the string
        str_row = str(row)[1:-1].strip("'")
        # Get the first column's element
        split1 = str_row.split(':')
        col1.append(split1[0])
        # Get the second column's element
        split2 = split1[1].split(' ')
        col2.append(split2[0])
        # Join everything after the second column's element
        # to get the third column's element
        split3 = ' '.join([v for v in split2[1:]])
        col3.append(split3)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':col1, 'b':col2, 'c':col3})
print(df)
```

Produces

```
         a      b              c
  0  abc    def  How I met her
  1  ter  kpefe   Hi I am this
```

Like I mentioned, I'm making the naive assumption that all of your data in structured in this way. Also if you don't want to manually put in the column names (for scalability) then you can use this nifty trick (which will automatically put integers as column names) to build the dataframe (referencing [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522724/take-multiple-lists-into-dataframe)):

```
# Gives the same desired output
df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, zip(col1, col2, col3))))
```

Answer (score 2):

***setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """abc:def How I met her
ter:kpefe Hi I am this"""

s = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='|', header=None, squeeze=True)

s

0     abc:def How I met her
1    ter:kpefe Hi I am this
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

***solution***
*use `str.extract`*

```
s.str.extract('(?P<a>\S+):(?P<b>\S+)\s+(?P<c>.*)', expand=True)

     a      b              c
0  abc    def  How I met her
1  ter  kpefe   Hi I am this
```