# How to insert dates in columns using python

Tags: python

I have two list:

```
run = ['2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05']
curr = ['2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06']
```

i want to insert dates into table **vv_flag** in columns run_date and curr_date respectively. like:

```
run_date      curr_date
2019-01-03    2019-01-04
2019-01-04    2019-01-05

query = "select run_date, curr_date from cdedev.vv_flag where flag = 'N'"
ress = cur.execute(query)
print(ress)
result = cur.fetchall()
run = result['run_date']
curr = result['curr_date']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take multiple lists into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522724/take-multiple-lists-into-dataframe)

Comment: Please explain it a little bit more. what have you tried till, any code snippet ?

Comment: i extracted list of dates from a particular table. now i want to insert those dates list into another table like shown above. i'm using insert query to insert dates in columns but how to iterate for whole dates ?

Comment: What do you mean "into table"? Are you using an SQL database? the Pandas dataframes? Plain Python lists? Or just what exactly? It would help to see the code you used to extract the dates, that would at least help explain what you are doing....

Comment: query = "select run_date, curr_date from cdedev.vv_flag where flag = 'N'"
ress = cur.execute(query)
print(ress)
result = cur.fetchall()
run = result['run_date']
curr = result['curr_date']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider you are using mysql.
First you have to establish connection.
Then you have to iterate through two list in parallel.
Then you have to use it along with the query.
Always make commits in bulk to reduce time.
`mydb.commit()` It is required to make the changes, otherwise no changes are made to the table.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
  )

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
run = ['2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05']
curr = ['2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06']
for i,j in zip(run,curr):
   query = "insert into vv_flag(run_date,curr_date) values ('{0}','{1}') where flag = 'N'".format(i,j)
   mycursor.execute(query)

mydb.commit()
```

Comment: You need to get `run` and `curr` from his previous query: `run, curr = zip(*result)`