# Python, Take Multiple Lists and Putting into pd.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen a variety of answers to this question [(like this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522724/take-multiple-lists-into-dataframe), and have had no success in getting my lists into one dataframe. I have one header list (meant to be column headers), and then a variable that has multiple records in it:

```
list1 = ['Rank', 'Athlete', 'Distance', 'Runs', 'Longest', 'Avg. Pace', 'Elev. Gain']

list2 = (['1', 'Jack', '57.4 km', '4', '21.7 km', '5:57 /km', '994 m']
['2', 'Jill', '34.0 km', '2', '17.9 km', '5:27 /km', '152 m']
['3', 'Kelsey', '32.6 km', '2', '21.3 km', '5:46 /km', '141 m'])
```

When I try something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['1', 'Jack, '57.4 km', '4', '21.7 km', '5:57 /km', '994 m'],
#                                      ['2', 'Jill', '34.0 km', '2', '17.9 km', '5:27 /km', '152 m'])))
```

It lists all the attributes as their own rows, like so:

```
    0   1
0   1   2
1   Jack    Jill
2   57.4 km 34.0 km
3   4   2
4   21.7 km 17.9 km
5   5:57 /km    5:27 /km
6   994 m   152 m
```

How do I get this into a frame that has `list1` as the headers, and the rest of the data neatly squared away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
list1 = ['Rank', 'Athlete', 'Distance', 'Runs', 'Longest', 'Avg. Pace', 'Elev. Gain']
list2 = (['1', 'Jack', '57.4 km', '4', '21.7 km', '5:57 /km', '994 m'],
    ['2', 'Jill', '34.0 km', '2', '17.9 km', '5:27 /km', '152 m'],
    ['3', 'Kelsey', '32.6 km', '2', '21.3 km', '5:46 /km', '141 m'])
```

do

```
pd.DataFrame(list2, columns=list1)
```

which returns

```
  Rank Athlete Distance Runs  Longest Avg. Pace Elev. Gain
0    1    Jack  57.4 km    4  21.7 km  5:57 /km      994 m
1    2    Jill  34.0 km    2  17.9 km  5:27 /km      152 m
2    3  Kelsey  32.6 km    2  21.3 km  5:46 /km      141 m
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your second list into a list of lists and then
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns = list1, data = list2)`

Comment: What's the best way to change something into a lists of lists?

Comment: Your list2 should look like 
`list2 = [['1', 'Jack', '57.4 km', '4', '21.7 km', '5:57 /km', '994 m'],
['2', 'Jill', '34.0 km', '2', '17.9 km', '5:27 /km', '152 m'],
['3', 'Kelsey', '32.6 km', '2', '21.3 km', '5:46 /km', '141 m']]`

Comment: I threw this in there: `i=0
    new_list=[]
    while i<len(myrow):
        new_list.append(list2[i:i+7])
        i+=7` , but it only returns the last row. interesting